How to show tthe last form in a modal?
<!-- Modal login -->
<div class="modal login fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header border-0">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Login/New Registration/Subscribers</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-02 justify-content-center" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="login-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#login" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-selected="false"> <span>Login</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="register-tab1" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#register" role="tab" aria-controls="register" aria-selected="true"><span>Advertise</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="register-tab2" name="register-tab2" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#subscribe" role="tab" aria-controls="register" aria-selected="true"><span>Subscribe</span></a>
          </li>

        </ul>
<!-- Business login Only -->        
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="login-tab">
            <form class="row mt-4 align-items-center" action="/" method="post" name="Login_Form" id="Login_Form">
        Modal1        
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
<!-- Business Registration Only -->            
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="register" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="register-tab">
            <form class="row mt-4 mb-5 align-items-center" method="post" action="/" name="Advertiser_Form" id="Advertiser_Form">
               
            Modal2  
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
<!-- Subscribers Registration Only -->            
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="subscribe" name="subscribe" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="subsriber-tab">
                        
            <form class="row mt-4 mb-5 align-items-center" method="post" action="/" name="Subscriber_Form" id="Subscriber_Form">
              Modal3
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Modal login -->

$('#loginModal').modal('show');  shows Modal1 the login form. How do I get it to show modal3 the subscribe form instead?
Is it possible?
I want to show any errors from posting the form contents with the correct form being diplayed rather than showing the Log In Form
thanks
